# What's the proper way to extract data from a google protobuff object?

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-vision

I have never encountered this sort of collection or object before until now (its the response from a request to Google-Cloud-Vision API).

I wrote a class that uses the API and does what I want correctly. However the only way that I can extract/manipulate data in the response is by using this module:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
```

I basically serialized the protobuff into a string and then used regex to get the data that I want.

There MUST be a better way than this. Any suggestions? I was hoping to have the API response give me a json dict or json dict of dicts etc... All I could come up with was turning the response into a string though.

Here is the file from the github repository:
[image_analyzer.py](https://github.com/rootVIII/image_analyzer/blob/master/image_analyzer.py)

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in `json` module will parse the string into a dictionary, like `json.loads(MessageToJson(response1))`.

Comment: Ok but the protobuff must me serialized to a string first I take it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the fields in the message object directly, e.g.:

```
response1 = vision_client.face_detection(image=image)
print(response1)
print(response1.face_annotations[0].detection_confidence)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that one doesn't work. That's the reason I had to serialize the response in the first place: This error results if you want to do more than just print the object:  x = response1.detectionConfidence
AttributeError: 'AnnotateImageResponse' object has no attribute 'detectionConfidence'

Comment: @JamesColley I probably got the property name wrong, tried to fix based on https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/cloud/vision/v1/image_annotator.proto . However the correct property names should be visible when you print the object.